# Angular 4 set a random string value from array to template and change to another string after two seconds

Tags: angular

I am working on a loading screen where it transitions between an array of words. I cannot seem to get Math.random to work as my verb value always ends up as 0. It also never updates the page or changes the value after a delay even if I set the updated verb in updateWord() to [1].

```
verbList = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
verb = '';

ngOnInit () {
const wordWait = 2000;
verb = this.verbList[Math.floor(Math.random()) * this.verbList.Length];
setTimeout(() => this.updateWord(), wordWait);
}

updateWord () {
verb = this.verbList[Math.floor(Math.random()) * this.verbList.Length];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your code.
The problem is that you have to multiply before applying `Math.floor()`

```
this.verb = this.verbList[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.verbList.length)];
```

Here an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-random-generator-string?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I KNEW it was something like that and I just couldn't find my error. Thank you so much!

Comment: I did but I have less than 15 reputation so I don't believe that it will show.